# Linux sed command to wrap yaml date string with single quotes

Tags: bash, sed

I have some files containing yaml where I need to add single quotes around the values of some date fields.

For example:

```
pubDate: 2016-10-10T08:22:00.000Z
```

Should be updated to

```
pubDate: '2016-10-10T08:22:00.000Z'
```

I think this can be done using something like sed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/^pubDate: \([-:.[:alnum:]]\+\)$/pubDate: '"'"'\1'"'"'/' FILE
```

I assume that `pubDate: <timestamp>` is the only content on the line.

Comment: With a YAML file you can assume that there are spaces or tabs in front of it.

Answer (score 1):

using awk

```
awk '/pubDate:/{$NF="\047"$NF"\047";print}'
```

for the file will look like this

```
awk -i inplace '{if(/pubDate:/)$NF="\047"$NF"\047";print}' FILE
```